# Get reference to std::exception held by std::exception_ptr

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am trying to get reference to `std::exception` which is held by `std::exception_ptr`.

Here's what I have tried:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

auto unwrap(std::exception_ptr ptr) -> const std::exception &
{
    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(ptr);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        return e;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const auto ptr = std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error{"test"});
    const auto &exp = unwrap(ptr);
    std::cout << exp.what() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With GCC, stdout shows "test" which is what I expected.
However, with MSVC 2019, stdout shows "Unknown exception".

Is there any undefined, unspecified, or implementation dependent behavior in my source code?
Or, is it a compiler/standard library implementation bug?

Comment: Note that you are missing some includes.

Comment: I think your problem is a dangling reference because it appears that that the reference of `e` is no longer valid outside of the catch block. If you put your logging inside the catch block, msvc prints the expected result. Seems like msvc makes a temporary copy of the exception or something.

Comment: My guess is that MSVC implementation throws a copy of exception to avoid introducing potential data race, this behavior seems to be allowed by the standard: **[propagation]** *If rethrow_exception rethrows the same exception object (rather than a copy), concurrent access to that rethrown exception object may introduce a data race.*

Comment: @user7860670 I think your comment is correct. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @user7860670 MSVC does it for ABI reasons. Exceptions are allocated on the stack and must be copied onto the heap to be stored in an exception_ptr (An exception_ptr is just a `shared_ptr` in the MSVC standard library)

Answer (score 1):

MSVC makes copies of your exception for some reason. Not sure if this is allowed by the standard or not (someone please clarify). The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std::literals;

struct myerror : std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;

    myerror(const myerror& o) : myerror(o.what())
    {
        std::cout << "exception is copied\n";
    }

    myerror(const myerror&& o) noexcept : myerror(o.what())
    {
        std::cout << "exception is moved\n";
    }
};

auto unwrap(std::exception_ptr ptr) -> const std::exception&
{
    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(ptr);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return e;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::exception_ptr ptr;
    try
    {
        throw myerror{ "test" };
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ptr = std::current_exception();
    }
    const auto& exp = unwrap(ptr);
    std::cout << exp.what() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints with MSVC (16.9):

```
exception is copied
exception is copied
test
Unknown exception
```

and with clang:

```
test
test
```

So your exception reference is dangling in MSVC's case.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zK3ce6c1K)

Comment: Yes, I did observe this too. What I want to know is that this behavior is allowed or not by standard.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer/reference to an exception beyond the scope of the corresponding try/catch will lead to a dangling pointer/reference (i.e. UB), and holding a `std::exception_ptr` doesn't change that.

There is no way to get a reference to the exception "held by" `std::exception_ptr`. `std::exception_ptr` is not necessarily a pointer/reference, the wrapped exception may also be a copy. In fact, MSVC implements it by means of a copy and so the pointer dangles as soon as `std::exception_ptr` goes out of scope.

`std::make_exception_ptr` is [implemented](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/support.exception#propagation-11) in terms of `std::current_exception()`, which, in turn is specified as ([[support.exception.propagation]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/support.exception#propagation-8)):

> `exception_ptr current_exception() noexcept;`
>
> *Returns:* An `exception_­ptr` object that refers to the currently handled exception or a **copy** of the currently handled exception, or a null `exception_­ptr` object if no exception is being handled.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to point out here. This is not about how std::current_exception() works. I just want to access to what std::exception_ptr refers. I don't care std::exception_ptr refers original one or copied one.

Comment: What I mean is there is no way to get a reference to the exception held by std::exception_ptr. `return e;` by reference will lead to undefined behavior in any case. `make_exception_ptr` is the only way (apart from current_exception) to obtain a non-empty `exception_ptr`.

Comment: `std::exception_ptr` acts as a pointer because it must satisfy Cpp17NullablePointer requirements.

Comment: @slyx `return e;` returns a dangling reference if `e` is a copy of the exception. You must use the exception in the scope of the handle, like: https://godbolt.org/z/K1cPT56za

Comment: @user7860670 of course but it may "point" to an internal copy of the exception, which it does in e.g. MSVC. And so the pointer dangles when `exception_ptr` goes out of scope.